# Kivy: How to load images from a list by a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, kivy

I have list with paths to images:

```
images = ['./picture0.png', './picture1.png', './picture2.png']
```

My app displays only first image `picture0.png`, as I have declared it manually using `StringProperty` with a path to the first image, stored under `pic` variable in the class.

```
image = StringProperty(images[0])
```

And then in `.kv` file the image is read by:

```
AsyncImage:
    source: root.pic
```

The thing I strive to do, is each time I click on the button, the displayed image is changed for the next one from the list. **Note the amount of the elements in a list changes**.

I guess it can be done using `StringProperty`, a `for loop` going through the images stored under the `images` variable and `id`s inside the `.kv` file, but I have no idea how to display them one by one, instead all in once. I was fiddling with a code, trying to come up with something useful and that's why I have created `Picture` class and not finished `display` method.

*my main.py file:*

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty


images = ['./picture0.png', './picture1.png', './picture2.png']


class Picture(BoxLayout):
    source = StringProperty(None)


class Test(BoxLayout):
    image = StringProperty(images[0])

    def hit_button(self):
        self.btn = display()


def display():
    for filename in images:
        pic = Picture(source=filename)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

*my .kv file:*

```
<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        rows: 2
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'click'
            AsyncImage:
                source: root.image


<Picture>
    Image:
        id: img
        source: root.source
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to keep track of where you are in the `images` list. You can do that a `NumericProperty()`, like this:

```
class Test(BoxLayout):
    image = StringProperty(images[0])
    index = NumericProperty(0)

    def hit_button(self):
        self.index += 1
        self.index %= len(images)
        self.image = images[self.index]
```

Also needed to specify the action for the `Button` in the `kv`:

```
<Test>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        rows: 2
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'click'
                on_release: root.hit_button()
            AsyncImage:
                source: root.image
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I really like the way you used modulo to select particular images in order.